# iTerm2 - Cannot display unicode characters

Tags: macos, iterm2

Obviously that was an issue with version 3.0.14. Updated to 3.0.15 and the problem is solved.

---

In OS X El Capitan I cannot display unicode characters in iTerm2 (Build 3.0.14).

I have set terminal emulation's character encoding to Unicode (UTF-8) in

`Preferences > Profiles > Default Profile > Terminal > Terminal emulation`

But still I cannot display or paste for instance German umlauts (ä, ö, ü) into the terminal despite the correct setting.

What am I missing?

Apple's Terminal works flawlessly, but I don't want to switch from iTerm2.

Answer (score 3):

In my case this helped: check the box to [set locale variables automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LfUC.png) (in every profile).

Works for new tabs in running app and for all tabs after restart.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue and it turned out I needed to enable the "Unicode Hex Input" in my OS System Preferences.

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources

Then click the plus sign at the bottom left and scroll to the bottom and select "Unicode Hex Input" from the list of options available.